# Indent an XML file in a VIM script

Tags: xml, vim

I am trying to write a nifty little GVIM script to do the following on Windows:

```
" get the contents from the Windows clipboard
put *
" set XML as the type of the current file
set filetype=xml
" put each XML tag on separate lines
%s/>\s\+</>\r</g
" Autoindent the file
gg=G
```

I'm stuck at the last command: it doesn't work from a script. Is there an equivalent that would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:normal` command allows you to execute normal commands:

```
:normal gg=G
```

See `:h :norm` for more information

Comment: And it's best to default to the `:normal!` variant with `!` to make this independent of any mappings (unless those are needed).